# Improper integral : the case $\infty-\infty.$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Determine whether $$\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx$$ converges or diverges.

According to wolfram alpha, this integral diverges so I want to prove this diverges.

The point where $\dfrac{\log x}{(x-1)^2}$ is not defined is $x=1$ so I separate integral :
$$\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx
=\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx+\int_{1}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx.
$$

Then, by simple calculation, I get $I_1:=\displaystyle\int_{1/2}^1\dfrac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx=-\infty,$ and $\displaystyle I_2:=\int_{1}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx=\infty$. $\bigg($ Note $\displaystyle\int \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2}\ dx=\log|1-x|+\frac{x\log x}{1-x}.\bigg)$

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx=I_1+I_2=-\infty +\infty.$

---

I calculated this improper integral in accordance with the definition of impropert integral, and I derive $-\infty+\infty$ (indeterminate form).

So I'm stacked how I show the divergence of $\displaystyle\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have $-\infty +\infty$ as in $\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x}\, dx$  then that would show lack of convergence

Comment: As soon as you showed that the first integral was $-\infty$ you were done.  If one piece diverges, the whole thing is divergent.

Comment: P.I.V. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral_%281%2F2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%28lnx%2F%28x-1%29%5E2%29dx

Comment: Usually, the definition of improper integrals says that if $\int_{1/2}^{1} f(x)\ dx$ diverges, then we consider that $\int_{1/2}^{2/3} f(x)\ dx$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

We have to study the integrability around $x=1$.

We have that:
$$\log(x)=\log((x-1)+1)\,\,\sim\,\, x-1$$

Note: $x-1\to 0$ when $x\to 1$. So:
$$\frac{\log(x)}{(x-1)^2}\,\,\sim\,\, \frac1{x-1}$$

By the asymptotic test, we shall conclude that the integral:
$$\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx$$
diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\frac{\log(x+1)}{x^2}$ has a simple pole at $x=0$, hence for any $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ the integral $I(a)=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$ is divergent. On the other hand, if we consider the Cauchy principal value

$$\text{PV}\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2}\,dx=\text{PV}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\log(1+x)+\log(1-x)}{x^2}\,dx $$
we get a finite number:

$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{x^2}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1/2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{n}\,dx = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}n(2n-1)}=\color{red}{4\ln 2-3\ln 3}.$$